# Power a coil with a MOSFET driven by a BJT in ground

Tags: mosfet, transformer, bjt, coil, pnp

I am trying to do something something maybe trivial. I have little to no knowledge in transistors so bear with me.

I want to power a high voltage coil with a low current switch using transistors I have at hand.

The working circuit is simple with a high current switch:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbXqzn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My idea is to drive it with an n-channel e-MOSFET I have at hand, a [CEP83A3](http://web2.cetsemi.com/PDF/TO-220-263-N/CET_CEP83A3.PDF), but since the switch has to be in the negative side of the circuit, I thought that with an PNP transistor I could make it work with no success. This is my basic idea:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEvvIs.png)</sup>

I tried with voltage dividers in different places to lower the input to the MOSFET but had mixed results, none of them worth showing. I have seen the push pull output configuration, but not sure if it will work with my setup having the switch in the negative side.

I did search here and Google but found nothing with a switch in the negative side.

Could someone help me with this? Maybe with a little explanation to know what is going on.

Thank you for your time spent reading this.

Comment: Why are you so insistent on having the switch with one end connected to zero volts?

Comment: The diagram you have should work but is missing two components.  You need to limit the base current in Q2 with a series resistor in the base or you will damage the part, about 10k should do it. You also need to provide bias for M1 when Q2 is turned off or it will just switch once and stay that way. About 10k between the gate and ground should work there too. 
You also need to consider the effect of back-emf on M2 when the large coil is turned off, that can generate 100's of volts more than the FET can take.  A couple diodes will help protect it.

Comment: @JasonMorgan I am trying to power the coil in my old car with it for fun/testing purposes. I do not use it regularly, so I like to try things with it when I have time. I have never liked the switch in the distributor that tends to get corroded with the spark it generates and then after some weeks sitting in a humid place, I have to keep cleaning it.
I will test what you propose with the two resistors and will let you know how it goes, thank you.

Comment: You should have put that information in your question! Top tip: Better questions =  Better answers. You need a few more changes. There's 100's of volts across the FET when it turns off. Coils like that work on the rate of change of current. So your fet needs to run on and off fast. The FET you specify is only good for about 30V.  Add a 27V power zener across the FET.  Change the resistor from the FETs get to ground to about 100 ohms, that will turn off the FET faster = more voltage.  Really for such a circuit you should be using a push-pull driver, but that's too complicated for your level.

Comment: Thank you @JasonMorgan, I will have in mind that all details are useful for questions. I tried the circuit with a load and worked as expected but then with the coil, it failed as you pointed out with my mosfet. Thanks to the zener, the mosfet survived (I blew two mosfets by not paying attention) but no spark and the small zener glowed before failing. I had one for 5W but I cannot find it and three for 1W that I used (and got burnt). Lastly I got a mosfet [12N10](http://www.utc-ic.com/uploadfile/2012/0502/20120502103220417.pdf). Will it survive? I have no idea how many volts gets to the mosfet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transformer is a typical automotive coil:
LP = 8mH
RP = 15Ohms
RATIO = 1:100
LS = LP * POW(RATIO,2)
RS = 100kOhms

I did not have time to put proper models in for suitable transistors and diodes, so pick a 27V zener diode in a large package.

A push-pull driver rather than a single PNP will produce larger voltages as it's the rate of change of current that effects the magnitude of the output. The rate of change of current is limited here by the 100R resistor combined with the gate capacitance of the FET.

***WARNING:  This circuit will produce pulses of about 3kV, that could cause serious harm or even death, especially if you have a heart condition - academic interest only, please don't build it.***

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuN9PV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This circuit worked for me, but for my setup, the zener was not necessary and had to check the polarity of the ignition coil or the mosfet gets destroyed.

Comment: The Zener IS necessary.  The back EMF is in 100's of volts and the FET is good for about 30. It may not die immediatly but will be damaged a little more each time the circuit operates.  Obviously including it is your choice.

Comment: Thank you again @JasonMorgan I kept thinking about the reverse polarity of the coil, it would bring different problems to the spark plug. I have a bunch of CEP50N06 rated for 60V and 50A, went and bought a 1N5369B zener rated for 51V using your circuit and now it works wonders. The spark is hotter than before and now it is "jumping" to the correct side of the spark plug. Now I can use both polarities of the coil though clearly I wanted the correct one. Now I need a stress test, I am packaging it with a heatsink. I need about 530Hz, I believe, for 8krpm.

Comment: Sounds like you are having fun! Be careful though. If you like my answer, kindly upvote.